# Swiftの教本を探しています

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

以下の条件でSwiftの教本を探しています。

・逆引きリファレンス本

今回でSwift教本の購入は、3冊目となります。
以下、今までの購入本です。

●1冊目：超初心者の本
絶対に挫折しない iPhoneアプリ開発「超」入門【Swift ＆ iOS8.1以降 完全対応】 高橋 京介

●2冊目：テキストコード（CUIプログラミング）の解説本
XcodeではじめるSwiftプロ​グラミング 大津 真

これらを踏まえて、オススメの本があればご教授ください。

なお、現在検討中の本は以下の2冊です。

●[詳解 Swift 荻原 剛志](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00TO6KMBI)
●詳細！Swift iPhoneアプリ開発 入門ノート Swift 1.1+Xcode 6.1+iOS 8.1対応 大重 美幸

Answer (score 1):

逆引きリファレンス本という目的なら、詳解Swiftをおすすめします。先日購入しましたが、文法について詳しく解説されてます。補足としてC言語では◯◯だったが、Swiftでは◯◯、、とかObj-cでは◯◯だったが、Swiftでは◯◯などと、比較して書かれているので個人的には各ポイントが頭に残りやすかったです。あとは、先週にswift2対応の改訂版が発売されたのでそちらをおすすめします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり詳解Swiftは評判がいいですね。とても参考になりました。